# Droppable containers not responding to draggable elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hello I'm in a situation where the user can Drag and Drop in a calendar situation. If the user takes something off of the calender I replace the spaces with new dropable divs; they have the same scope as the other draggable + dropable elements, but you cannot drop anything onto them. There's no errors, it just reverts as if you dropped them onto a incompatible element.

Comment: Can you display your code used to implement this?

Comment: I use this function to call the Draggable and Droppable:: http://pastebin.com/sahLKEzg